# Bluetooth scan is not working in foreground service JAVA for android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, background-service

I want to scan Bluetooth device on foreground. I created foreground service and added bluetooth scan code to foreground service. This service and bluetooth scan are working when phone screen is on  but when phone screen is off service is working , bluetooth scan is not working. I showed bluetooth scan code on below in while function blok.

This is my code :

```
public class foregroundService extends Service {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION_PERMISSION = 2;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private List<String> discoveredDevicesList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, String> users = new HashMap<>();
private BroadcastReceiver discoveryReceiver;



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    while (true) {
                        Log.d("Tag", "service is running");
                        if (discoveryReceiver == null) { //THIS IS MY BLUETOOTH SCAN CODE
                            discoveryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

                                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


                                    String action = intent.getAction();
                                    if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,

                                                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,},
                                                    REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
                                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,

                                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,},
                                                    REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);

                                            return;
                                        }
                                        if (device != null && device.getName() != null) {
                                            String deviceName = device.getName();

                                            if (!discoveredDevicesList.contains(deviceName)) {
                                                System.out.println("Foreground bluetoothscan" + device.getName());
                                                users.put("Name", device.getName());
                                                Toast.makeText(context, device.getName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                discoveredDevicesList.add(deviceName);

                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            registerReceiver(discoveryReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
                        }

                        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(9000);


                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    ).start();
    final String CHANNEL_ID="Foreground Service";
    NotificationChannel channel =new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);

    Notification.Builder notification=new Notification.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentText("Foreground service is running").setContentTitle("This is titile");
    startForeground(1001,notification.build());

return  super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```